# tcp session - http request [ x out of y] in wireshark capture

Tags: http, tcp, wireshark, tcpip, tcpdump

As below, i am seeing this [HTTP request 1/2] and [HTTP request 2/2] in 2 separate payload, are they separate GET request in a single tcp session or are they the same GET request ???

[image]
[image]

====

Added full captured
Pic1
[image]

Pic2
[image]
Pic3
[image]

Comment: One of the TCP packets show sequence `1` where the other shows sequence `10`, and there are differences in the TCP options for the `TSval` and the `TSecr` for whatever that is worth from the obvious look over.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that these are two requests in the same connection because:

- The endpoints of the connection, i.e. source port, source IP, destination port and destination IP for both requests are exactly the same. Usually the source port if ephemeral and does not get reused quickly for another connection.
- The first request has a (relative) start sequence of 1 with a length of 9 and the second seems to immediately follow this by having a start sequence of 10.
- The timing information shown suggest that these requests are close together.

But, it is impossible to be definite about this without seeing more parts of the connection, i.e. to find out if there was a connection teardown (FIN) and setup (SYN) for the same endpoints between the requests.

Note that if these are actually two requests within the same connection then these are very strange behaving HTTP client and server or no (proper) HTTP at all. If seen as HTTP as parsed by wireshark the client would do a HTTP 0.9 request (single line in request, i.e. no full HTTP/1.x header) which is uncommon in the first place (obsolete since ages). Additionally the server would do HTTP keep-alive (i.e. multiple HTTP requests within a single TCP connection) despite the HTTP 0.9 request even though HTTP keep alive is only defined since HTTP 1.0 with an explicit `Connection: keep-alive` header in the request or since HTTP 1.1 implicitly.

Comment: hi steffen, i updated my original post with the full capture. Are you able to tell if the 2 GET is normal.  if they belong in the same session, are they 2 separate GET request ?

Comment: @Noob: This does not provide all required information either since you only show the details of a single request. But given that Wireshark claims that this is HTTP request 2/2 it is even more likely that this is the same TCP connection. To be really sure use [follow the TCP stream](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html) from one request and see if the other request is in the same TCP connection. And again, if these are two HTTP 0.9 requests in the same connection it is not normal since with HTTP 0.9 only a single request is allowed per TCP connection.